# How render text in qtip2..?

Tags: jquery, qtip, qtip2

I need to pick up before the show each value of

```
$('a#functionDescription').attr('title')
```

How do this..?

```
   $('a#functionDescription').qtip({
        content: { 
            text: false
        },
        style: {
            width: 250,
            tip: 'leftMiddle',
            color: 'white',
            background: '#66CC33',
            name: 'green'
        },
        position: {
            corner: { 
                target: 'topRight',
                tooltip: 'bottomLeft'
            },
            adjust: { x: 0, y: -25 }
        },
        events: {
            render: function(event, api) {
                //what to write here ?
            }
        }
    });
```

**update:**

$('a#functionDescription').attr('title') is changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `text` as a function:

```
content: {
    text: function() {
        return $(this).attr('title');
    }
}
```

Inside the function `this` will be the element being hovered. There is no need to use any event.

Comment: $('a#functionDescription').attr('title') is changed

Comment: @simplydenis: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a#functionDescription').qtip({
        content: { 
            text: $(this).attr('title'); //Replace this with any element attributes
        },
        style: {
            width: 250,
            tip: 'leftMiddle',
            color: 'white',
            background: '#66CC33',
            name: 'green'
        },
        position: {
            corner: { 
                target: 'topRight',
                tooltip: 'bottomLeft'
            },
            adjust: { x: 0, y: -25 }
        },
        events: {
            render: function(event, api) {
                //what to write here ?
            }
        }
    });
```

You can grab at Content any of element attributes.